# QGIS Google Hybrid layer error

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin

The Google hybrid layer from the OpenLayers Plugin is no longer working for any of our maps. It's gone completely blank, and uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin hasn't resolved the issue.

Has anyone else experienced this and knows how to address the problem?

Sorry for the vagueness of the question, or if this is a duplication, but I'm still something of a novice with QGIS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a QGIS novice, you should not waste your time with the outdated openlayers plugin.

There is the new QuickMapServices plugin to fit your needs better. You have to enable the `Contributed services` in the Settings dialogue to get the Google layers.

Please respect the Google terms of license, and be prepared that they might remove or change layers some day without further notice. You get what you paid for (i.e. nothing).